# Why is it that the image I use for my nav_bar button has white edges?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder, uibarbuttonitem

[image: Nav Bar Button looking bad]

I'm trying to use this image through interface builder, but it makes this weird white space on the outside. I cant change it in the program because of how everything is set up, or at least if I do it will involve rewriting the whole thing from scratch. Is there some way to add custom navigation bar buttons through IB without having this issue ??

**UPDATE**

[image: Add a Button to the Bar Button]

Once I had added the button to the bar button I could customize it as needed, and achieve the result required, by changing the qualities of the button I added to Custom in IB.

[image: Now its looking good!]

Comment: some where size problem...of image and Btton size. both are different..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply remove the rounded rect type from the `UIButton` declaration and write  :-

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

instead of

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

Comment: You can achieve this directly from IB or from your code as answered by @IronManGill

Comment: Ah Yes But I was trying to do it directly from a bar_button, I first needed to add a "regular" (rounded-rect/custom) button into the bar_button. Thanks for the help Hemang & IronManGill :D